# ansible regex_search with variable

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-template

How to find a match using regex in ansible playbook where variable appears in the `regex_search` argument?

The following playbook doesn't find the match... when run using: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - set_fact:
          pattern: "{{ 'foobar' | regex_search('foo') }}"
     - set_fact:
          m: "{{ 'beefoo' | regex_search('bee{{ pattern }}') }}"     
     - debug:
          msg: "hi {{ m }}"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on the `ansible`'s version you're using. As far as I know, you can use that expression in a version greater than 2.4.0. For lower versions you can use `regex_search('^' + pattern | string)`.

So your code will be something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - set_fact:
          pattern: "{{ 'foobar' | regex_search('foo') }}"
     - set_fact:
          m: "{{ 'beefoo' | regex_search('bee' + pattern | string) }}"     
     - debug:
          msg: 'hi ' + m | string
```

Comment: thanks, where do i put the `bee` in `'^' + pattern | string`?

Comment: Sorry, check it again, bad copy/paste and remember to upvote =)

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to share my complex case with positive look-ahead, positive look-behind and variable in `regex_search` for those who may need it.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - set_fact:
          pattern: "{{ 'foobar' | regex_search('foo') }}"
     - set_fact:
          m: "{{ 'beefoo' | regex_search('(?<=prefix-' + pattern | string + '-)' + '([0-9.]+)' + '(?=suffix)') }}"     
     - debug:
          msg: "hi {{ m }}"
```