# loop over a list of dictionaries in Ansible without knowing key names

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have been looking for a solution, none seems to work so far.

I have a task output registered as:

```json
"action_list.start_artifacts": [
    {
        "account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001": "docker run -d -p 21001:8080 -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001:/logs -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001/.configmap:/tibco/config -v /apps/gwportal/appdynamics/:/apps/gwportal/appdynamics/ --env-file /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001/config.env --name account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001 account-troubletree-v1:1.0.18"
    },
    {
        "account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002": "docker run -d -p 21002:8080 -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002:/logs -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002/.configmap:/tibco/config -v /apps/gwportal/appdynamics/:/apps/gwportal/appdynamics/ --env-file /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002/config.env --name account-tree-v1-1-0-17-21002 account-tree-v1:1.0.17"
    }
]
```

I am trying to get the key name using below task, but its failing.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}"
  loop: "{{ action_list.start_artifacts }}"
```

Comment: are the dictionary variables dynamic ? i mean do the variables (`account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001`, `account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002`) always have the same value ?

Comment: Yes they are dynamic , their value can change

Comment: ah okay, then why not use regex to search though the output and set facts using regex search - [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046531/ansible-regex-search-with-variable)  [link2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.keys()|first }}"
      loop: "{{ action_list.start_artifacts }}"
```

---

Next option is

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item|dict2items).0.key  }}"
      loop: "{{ action_list.start_artifacts }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, you are always a savior on ansible questions.
can you explain why ansible isn't able to get the key if I mention "{{ item[0].key }}" ?

Comment: This is a wrong question. Why do you expect the `key` method should be available?

Comment: Hmm, nevermind, I thought since looped item is a dictionary here, we could simply get the key of the dictionary but this .key attribute.

Comment: There is no `key` attribute. It's possible to create one by `item|dict2items`. I've added an example.

Comment: @VenuS [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) is a Python function on dictionaries. You can't just go and make it a singular, then expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to loop over dictionary variables is the variables are static of-course

- `default.yaml` having the variable

```yaml
action_list.start_artifacts:
  - account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001: "docker run -d -p 21001:8080 -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001:/logs -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001/.configmap:/tibco/config -v /apps/gwportal/appdynamics/:/apps/gwportal/appdynamics/ --env-file /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001/config.env --name account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001 account-troubletree-v1:1.0.18"
    account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002: "docker run -d -p 21002:8080 -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002:/logs -v /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002/.configmap:/tibco/config -v /apps/gwportal/appdynamics/:/apps/gwportal/appdynamics/ --env-file /apps/projects/logs/account-troubletree-v1-1-0-17-21002/config.env --name account-tree-v1-1-0-17-21002 account-tree-v1:1.0.17"
```

- task to use the variable

```yaml
- debug:
  msg: "{{ item.account-troubletree-v1-1-0-18-21001 }} "
  with_items: "{{ action_list.start_artifacts }}"
```

However if they are dynamic then we can go for solutions like
[regex-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046531/ansible-regex-search-with-variable)
[regex-filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)